# nginx limit_req_zone rate limiting doesn't work

Tags: nginx

limit_req_zone rate doesn't work  as i thought. No matter how much i set it ,it still works as rate=1r/s.

my nginx.conf:

```
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=lwrite:10m rate=300r/s;
    ...
    limit_req zone=lwrite burst=5;
```

after reading this doc (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html),I thought my nginx should only delay request when a ip visit more than 300r/s,and return 5xx when it visit more than 305/s.

however ,if I run test: *ab -c 12 -n 12 '127.0.0.1:8090/index.html?_echo=abc'*, the output is：

```
   Concurrency Level:      12  
   Time taken for tests:   0.051 seconds  
   Complete requests:      12  
   Failed requests:        6  
     (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 6, Exceptions: 0)  
   Write errors:           0  
  Non-2xx responses:      6
```

i found 5 warns and 6 errors in nginx error.log , it turns out only the first visit success immediately,the next 5 would be delay, and the last 6 returned error. So, no matter how high i set ,it still works as rate=1r/s.

why? Does anyone meet same problem with me? my nginx version is 1.5.13 and 1.7.11

Comment: Have you checked nginx config? Have you _restarted_ server?

Comment: yes i restarted server. And i only added those two lines to the default nginx.conf

Comment: exactly same problem here. did you solve it ? If i found the solution I will tell you